# Controlling order of Spring Bean Creation on external jar

Tags: spring-boot, spring-bean

I have a SpringBoot project where I have to load Encrypted Properties, so i have created a bean with for class `EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` for loading properties.
I am also loading beans from xml configuration from a jar which is provided by external team and unintentionally a Bean for same class `EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` is getting loaded from xml.

My issue is that I am unable to control the order of creation of above beans. So if bean defined by me gets loaded first then project works but if bean in jar file gets loaded first then project fails.

I cannot update bean in jar file, so cannot use `dependson` clause to load my bean first. I have tried using `@order` annotation but it doesn't help.

Can someone please advise on how to control order of beans here.